# Show In File Explorer not working on Android Studio 3.6.3 on Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-3.0

I'm using KDE Neon Linux Distro (based on Ubuntu).

When i right-click on a file in Project view the `Show In Explorer` menu is there (although the text is `Show In Dolphin` because i'm using Dolphin File Explorer). When I clicked it, file explorer loading indicator appeared but the file explorer never opened.

I've checked `idea.log` in `/home/<username>/.AndroidStudio3.6/system/log/` but can't find anything about the file explorer.

Here is latest lines of the log. The entire file contains 39,000 lines.

```
ms 
2020-05-06 17:02:21,947 [ 722495]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 121 ms 
2020-05-06 17:03:35,512 [ 796060]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appEditorColorsManagerImpl took 15 ms 
2020-05-06 17:03:35,586 [ 796134]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKatalibraryTable took 37 ms 
2020-05-06 17:03:35,587 [ 796135]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 143 ms 
2020-05-06 17:04:50,155 [ 870703]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/vcs/patch.svg' with '/icons/vcs/patch.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:04:50,182 [ 870730]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/vcs/Shelve.svg' with '/icons/vcs/Shelve.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:05:02,460 [ 883008]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKatalibraryTable took 20 ms 
2020-05-06 17:05:53,897 [ 934445]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/modules/testRoot.svg' with '/icons/modules/testRoot.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:06:09,811 [ 950359]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFindSettings took 24 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:09,834 [ 950382]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Module: 'app'FacetManager took 12 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:09,913 [ 950461]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKatalibraryTable took 36 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:09,923 [ 950471]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 167 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:17,948 [ 958496]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKatalibraryTable took 23 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:29,987 [ 970535]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/modules/testResourcesRoot.svg' with '/icons/modules/testResourcesRoot.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:06:29,992 [ 970540]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/modules/excludeRoot.svg' with '/icons/modules/excludeRoot.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:06:41,563 [ 982111]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKataRunManager took 15 ms, libraryTable took 77 ms 
2020-05-06 17:06:41,571 [ 982119]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 181 ms 
2020-05-06 17:07:50,844 [1051392]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/copyHovered.svg' with '/icons/general/copyHovered.svg' 
2020-05-06 17:07:52,725 [1053273]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [BukaKata] git /usr/bin/git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -- .idea/render.experimental.xml 
2020-05-06 17:07:55,404 [1055952]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFindSettings took 29 ms 
2020-05-06 17:07:55,501 [1056049]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/risal/AndroidStudioProjects/BukaKata' BukaKataRunManager took 27 ms, libraryTable took 31 ms 
2020-05-06 17:07:55,501 [1056049]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 161 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, it's very simple

just add `/home` inside the PATH variable in your `/etc/environment`, then restart

before
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

after
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home"`

Don't forget the `:` as separator